What factors affect variance in the bias-variance decomposition?
In the bias-variance decomposition:
$$\text{err} = \text{bias}^2 + \text{variance} + \text{irreducible error} \tag{1}$$
what factors affect the variance (second term)?
I was always thinking that there are only two factors that affect variance:

Number of training samples (more data less variance, just like the standard error decreases with more samples)
The learning algorithm (the function learned from a neural network is more "wiggly" compared to the one learned with linear regression)

Are these two the only factors that affect the variance?
An example
Taken from here the bias-variance decomposition of k-nn is:
$$Err(x_o)= \sigma_e^2+[f(x_o)-\frac{1}{k}\sum_{l=1}^{k}f(x_o)]^{2} + \frac{\sigma_e^2}{k}$$
with the last term being the variance. Since $\sigma_e$ is dependent on the problem at hand, can we say that variance depends also (not only for k-nn's but for all learners)

The random noise $e$?


For the record, current understanding of bias-variance is actually in question for overparametrized systems.  See Reconciling modern machine learning practice and the bias-variance trade-off  So this U-shaped decompositions may not be valid in modern setting.

The variance term in the bias-variance decomposition captures the sensitivity of the model to changes in the training data. You're correct that the number of training samples, the learning algorithm deciding model complexity, and the irreducible noise are key factors, but there are additional factors that also influence variance.
Firstly as for your question about the random irreducible noise in the data, it does contribute to the variance, especially in models that are more sensitive to noise such as your k-nn with k=1. This is because noise can cause the model to fluctuate more across different training sets, increasing variance. However, the noise itself is often considered part of the irreducible error, not the variance directly, but it influences how the variance term manifests in practice. That's why in the third variance term in your k-nn bias-variance equation you have the noise contribution.
Secondly, model hyperparameters such as regularization (Ridge, Lasso, dropout, early stopping, learning rate, batch size, etc) and model specific parameters (the number of k in your k-nn example) will affect variance. Regularization  can reduce variance by penalizing the complexity of the model, effectively controlling how "wiggly" the learned function is. And for your k-nn example, a smaller k increases variance as the model becomes more sensitive to individual data points, while a larger k smooths the predictions and reduces variance apparently. Similarly if your model is trained via SGD with a high learning rate hyperparameter, it might cause the model to overshoot the optimal parameter values increasing variance.
Finally, feature selection and engineering would also affect the variance component of the error. Including irrelevant or noisy features can increase the variance as the model might try to fit these features, leading to overfitting. Proper preprocessing of feature input such as normalization and scaling can improve variance as it ensures the optimization algorithm converges more efficiently to have a better trained model.

So the factors that affect the bias and variance extend to basically everything that is part of the ML pipeline? This make sense, since $\text{err} = \mathbb{E}[(y - \hat{y})^2]$ is affected by $\hat{y}$, which in turn affected by every aspect of the pipeline.

Exactly now you completely understand, hope you can accept or at least upvote my answer since it makes sense and seems helpful for your question.
